# Using generics, to strongly protect steps in a workflow system?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to grow my understanding of TS's generics system, with a hypothetical workflow system with series of steps. Starting with a `step` of a type `Step<TInput, KOutput>` where `TInput` and `KOutput` data that the a step requires/consumes and outputs/produces.

What's the idiomatic typescript way of implementing type-defing `Workflow<...>`?

So that the the compiler, guarantees that steps from one to another are compatible?

```js
class InitRandom implements Step<None, RandomNumber> { ... }
class Floor      implements Step<RandomNumber, Int> { ... }
class Square     implements Step<Int, Int> { ... }


// Compiler allows this...
let workflow = Workflow<InitRandom, Floor, Square>(...)

// ERROR: compiler catches this!
let workflow = Workflow<Floor, InitRandom, Square>(...)
                               ^
                               ^
                               ^--- incompatible input type

workflow.Run();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that since the type arguments to Workflow are themselves generic you'd need HKTs and TS doesn't have them. N.B. that if the steps are functions this is utterly trivial: composing/chaining function calls will not pass muster with the compiler if the inputs and outputs don't match. It's not clear why you need to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Could you flesh out those `...` and define undeclared things so that it's a [mre]?  I'm not sure what `Step`, `None`, `RandomNumber`, or `Int` are, or what the intended function arguments to `Workflow` are, or how many such arguments it accepts, or if `Run()` is supposed to have an output type, etc.

Comment: Like, it's *possible* that [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6xn0m) is what you want, but I had to add in so much stuff before I even started with `Workflow` that I don't know if it's your intent.

Comment: You could use a monad like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKpJKw) to achieve a typesafe workflow

Comment: Or your can do something like [here](https://tsplay.dev/NnlGqW)